# Prove that a linear transformation with $f^2-2f+\operatorname{Id}=0$ is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $f\colon \mathbb{R^4} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R^4}$. Prove that if $f$ is satisfying the relationship $${f^2} -{2f} +\operatorname{Id}_{\mathbb R^4}=0_{\mathbb R^4}$$ then $f$ is isomorphism  and then determine the inverse of $f$ (and kernel and range). (where $f^2$ is $f\circ f$.)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you edit your post to include the steps you have already taken?

Comment: Doesn't this polynomial remind you something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can rewrite $f^2-2f + \mathrm{Id} = 0$ as $\mathrm{Id} = f \circ (2 \mathrm{Id} - f)$.

Therefore, $f$ is an isomorphism, its inverse is $(2 \mathrm{Id} - f)$, and $\mathrm{Ker}(f)=0$ and $\mathrm{Im}(f)=\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: But how you get to Id=f circle (2Id-f) ?

Comment: Do you know what "linear" mean ?